# upload 2 images and retrieve first id from the database

Tags: php, debugging

I uploaded 2 images into the database and want to retrieve from the database by id... I dont know how to retrieve for the first ID. I can retrieve the second ID using :

```
$lastid = mysql_insert_id();


//declare where the image is from
$before = $row['image']; //want to retrieve first id
$after = $row['image']; //this can be get by the $lastid
```

///updated my codes

I declared like this :

```
  $lastid = mysql_insert_id();
    $pic = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images WHERE id='$lastid'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($pic);

    //declare where the image is from
    $before = $row['image'];
    $after = $row['image'];
```

when I output the image, i got 2 last id

Comment: Do you mean `$after = $lastid;`? I'm confused.

Comment: yes .... how can i get $before ? pls

Comment: Put `$before = $row['image'];` before `$lastid = mysql_insert_id();`?

Comment: are you running query in loop? can you show full code?

Comment: I declared like this :



    $lastid = mysql_insert_id();
    $pic = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images WHERE id='$lastid'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($pic);
    
    //declare where the image is from
    $before = $row['image'];
    $after = $row['image'];

when I output the image, i got 2 last id

Comment: update your question. Don't add code in comment.

Comment: @SkyBlue i asked you to add imagedata insertion code. Because you are inserting 2 images. We cant to see how you are doing. then only we can help you. But you added unwanted code.